# How do I use dependsOn on a copyIndex (array) resource?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm using an arm template to deploy topics and subscriptions. My resources to be deployed are of type `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` because I'm targeting a resource group external to where the deployment lives.

If the topics already exists, the template works. 
Because arm template resources are deploy in parallel, I need to have the topics deploy *before* the subscriptions - [this ordering is made possible by `dependsOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-define-dependencies).

**The problem I'm having is that because the `"name"` value of the topics have a `copyIndex()`, I'm not sure how I can target the topic resource.**

Among the many things I have tried, here are some:

- `[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].topic)]`
- `[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments',
  parameters('topics'))]`
- `["topicLoop"]`

Here are the topics and subscriptions resource objects in my template:

```
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), copyIndex())]",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('sharedResourcesResourceGroupName')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "topicLoop",
                "count": "[length(parameters('topics'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "2018-05-01",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('topics')[copyIndex()])]",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                            "properties": {}                  
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].topic, copyIndex())]",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('sharedResourcesResourceGroupName')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "subscriptionLoop",
                "count": "[length(parameters('subscriptions'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "2018-05-01",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].topic, '/', parameters('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].subscription)]",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                            "properties": {}          
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                // what goes here?! I need to have this depend on the topics 
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dependsOn` value is simply:

`"dependsOn" : ["topicLoop"]`

But it needed to be on the most external resource and not nested template.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `dependsOn` for each individual resource if you can generate its name. or you can hardcode those. either way, you can `dependsOn` the whole loop by using its name or individual resources inside the loop by referencing them by their name